# Gwt Logging into Client UI from Server-side

Tags: gwt, logging

I have created GWT app, in which I have a Vertical Panel where I log the details.

Client side logging I'm doing using logger

sample code is:

```
         public static VerticalPanel customLogArea = new VerticalPanel();
         public static Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
                    logerPanel.setTitle("Log");
        scrollPanel.add(customLogArea);
        logerPanel.add(scrollPanel);
        if (LogConfiguration.loggingIsEnabled()) {
        rootLogger.addHandler(new HasWidgetsLogHandler(customLogArea));

        }
```

And I'm updating my vertical log panel using this code

```
         rootLogger.log(Level.INFO,
                        "Already Present in Process Workspace\n");
```

But now my question is , I have to log server side details also into my vertical log panel.

My serverside GreetingServiceImpl code is:

```
      public boolean createDirectory(String fileName)
             throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Boolean result = false;
    try {
        rootLogger.log(Level.INFO,
                 "I want to log this to my UI vertical log Panel");

        system.out.println("log this to UI");
        File dir = new File("D:/GenomeSamples/" + fileName);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            result = dir.mkdir();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now I want to log sysoutprt statements to my UI from here. How can I achieve this. Now using rootLogger.log(Level.INFO,
                     "I want to log this to my UI vertical log Panel"); code it is logging this to eclipse console . But how to log this to my UI in client side.

Please let me know If anything wrong in this question.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you right, you want to see your server log entries in web interface. And of course, java logger and printStackTrace() won't help you in that: your gwt code is compiled to JavaScript and has nothing to do with console and log files. Besides, your server can't "push" log entries to client  - it's up to client to make requests. So if you want to track new log entries and move it to client, you need to poll server for new entries. And yet another problem: you may have many clients polling your servlet and you should keep in mind this multi-threading.

This is how I see probable implementation (it's just concept, may contain some errors and misspellings):

**Remote interface:**

```
public interface GreetingService extends RemoteService {
    List<String> getLogEntries();
    boolean createDirectory(String fileName)throws IllegalArgumentException;

}
```

**Remote Servlet:**

```
public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements GreetingService {

public static final String LOG_ENTRIES = "LogEntries";

public List<String> getLogEntries() {

    List<String> entries = getEntriesFromSession();
    List<String>copy = new ArrayList<String>(entries.size());
    copy.addAll(entries);
    //prevent loading the same entries twice
    entries.clear();
    return copy;

}



public boolean createDirectory(String fileName)throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Boolean result = false;
    try {

        log("I want to log this to my UI vertical log Panel");

        log("log this to UI");
        File dir = new File("D:/GenomeSamples/" + fileName);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            result = dir.mkdir();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log("Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}

private List<String> getEntriesFromSession()    {
    HttpSession session= getThreadLocalRequest().getSession();
    List<String>entries = (List<String>)session.getAttribute(LOG_ENTRIES);
    if (entries == null)    {
        entries = new ArrayList<String>();
        session.setAttribute(LOG_ENTRIES,entries);
    }

    return entries;

}

private void log(String message)  {
    getEntriesFromSession().add(message);
}
```

**Simple implementation of polling (gwt client-side):**

```
Timer t = new Timer() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    greetingAsyncService.getLogEntries(new AsyncCallBack<List<String>>() {
       void onSuccess(List<String>entries) {
         //put entries to your vertical panel
       }

       void onFailure(Throwable caught){
           //handle exceptions
       }
    });
  }
};

// Schedule the timer to run once in second.
t.scheduleRepeating(1000);

greetingAsyncService.createDirectory(fileName, new AsyncCallBack<Void>(){
    void onSuccess(List<String>entries) {
          //no need to poll anymore
          t.cancel();
       }

       void onFailure(Throwable caught){
           //handle exceptions
       }
});
```

}

As you can see, I have used session to keep log entries, because session is client-specific and so different clients will receive different logs. It's up to you to decide what to use -  you may create your own Logger class that will track users itself and give appropriate logs to appropriate clients.

And also you may want to save level of your messages (INFO,ERROR etc.) and then display messages in different colors (red for ERROR, for instance). To do so, you need to save not List, but some your custom class.

Comment: Thanks , I think according to ur sample code It will send list of strings from server to client and I have to use that list to update that vertical log panel ryt?? But I ll be having many methods and many classes and I want to log every method details to my logger. For ex inside createDirectory method I have sysout statement ryt, like wise I ll be having many sysout statements in many methods and I want to log all those sysout statement to my logger. Can u give some Idea how I can Implement ur sample code to my project.

Comment: Then you definitely need to encapsulate your logging functionality into separate class. Provide interface similar to Logger, and call your MyLogger.log or MyLogger.INFO or something, in your servlet methods. In getLogEntries() call something like MyLogger.getLogEntries(). Put MyLogger instance into HttpSession as I did above with log entries.

Comment: Can u make changes in ur answer, so that it ll be useful to understand

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a logging servlet that has the same methods as your logging framework to send log messages to your server via RPC.

Here are some sample RPC log methods you can use:

```
public interface LogService extends RemoteService {
    public void logException(String logger, String priority, String message, String error, StackTraceElement[] stackTrace, String nativeStack);
}

public interface LogServiceAsync {
    public void logException(String logger, String priority, String message, String error, StackTraceElement[] stackTrace, String nativeStack, AsyncCallback<Void> callback);
}

public class LogServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements LogService {

    public void logException(String loggerName, String priority, String logMessage, String errorMessage, StackTraceElement[] stackTrace, String nativeStack) {      
        Logger logger = getLogger(loggerName);
        Level level = getLevel(priority);
        // Create a Throwable to log
        Throwable caught = new Throwable();
        if (errorMessage != null && stackTrace != null) {
            caught = new Throwable(errorMessage);
            caught.setStackTrace(stackTrace);
        }
        //do stuff with the other passed arguments (optional)
        logger.log(level, message, caught);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, I think the sample code u have given will log into Eclipse console. I want that log to send back to client side.

Comment: Hi. No, my code logs messages to the server side, so you can write it to a file, or show it on the console. Sorry, that's what I thought you wanted. What you can do is either make Async calls to get new log messages, or use a WebSocket framework like [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) that will push new log messages from the server to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Although those implementations are very nice, forget about timers and repeated server queries. We've something better now.

It's possible to push data from server to client using [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) which supports [WebSockets](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).