# Gwt update TextArea from Server

Tags: java, gwt

I have created a Textarea in my app. And I have one method in my server i.e, in

```
              GreetingServiceImpl class
```

The sample code of my method in  GreetingServiceImpl class is:

```
        public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    System.out.println("input===>>" + input);
    String serverInfo = getServletContext().getServerInfo();
    System.out.println("serverinfo===>>" + serverInfo);
    String userAgent = getThreadLocalRequest().getHeader("User-Agent");
    System.out.println("User agent===" + userAgent);
    input = escapeHtml(input);
    System.out.println("2....input===>>" + input);
    userAgent = escapeHtml(userAgent);

    return "Hello, " + input + "!<br><br>I am running " + serverInfo
            + ".<br><br>It looks like you are using:<br>" + userAgent;
}
```

Now in my client I will call this method, after calling this method I want to setText to my textarea. The text should  come from the server.

```
   i.e, I have 4 sysout statements in this method.
  System.out.println("input===>>" + input);
 System.out.println("serverinfo===>>" + serverInfo);
  System.out.println("User agent===" + userAgent);
 System.out.println("2....input===>>" + input);
```

When these statements prints into eclipse console , at the same time I want to print this in order(one by one according to their execution)in my UI i.e, into my textarea. I have no Idea how to achieve this. Please tel me is this possible to do, if so how I can achieve?

PS: I'm looking for a logger type functionality which can update my textarea when ever any server side mathods executed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gwt Logging into Client UI from Server-side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876414/gwt-logging-into-client-ui-from-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to push data from server to client using [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) which supports [WebSockets](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [RPC](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) calls? It is straightforward and easy.

You just create an Example.java and ExampleAsync class at client, and the implementation at server. You can then call the implementation with an  AsyncCallback.

For example:

```
 callback = new AsyncCallback() {
    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
      // Make what ever you want! For example, set the textarea
    }
```

On the other hand, if you want server to notify and update client, you can use [Server-Push](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ)
You can also use [gwt-comet](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/) , which also streams messages over http.